# SQL status changes with start and end dates

Tags: sql, aggregate-functions, window-functions

This is a table of user statuses over the period of 9/1/2021 to 9/10/2021. `1` means "active." `0` means "canceled."

| date | user | status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 9/1/2021 | 1 | 1 |
| 9/1/2021 | 2 | 0 |
| 9/1/2021 | 3 | 1 |
| 9/2/2021 | 1 | 1 |
| 9/2/2021 | 2 | 1 |
| 9/2/2021 | 3 | 1 |
| 9/3/2021 | 1 | 0 |
| 9/3/2021 | 2 | 1 |
| 9/3/2021 | 3 | 1 |
| 9/4/2021 | 1 | 0 |
| 9/4/2021 | 2 | 1 |
| 9/4/2021 | 3 | 1 |
| 9/5/2021 | 1 | 0 |
| 9/5/2021 | 2 | 1 |
| 9/5/2021 | 3 | 0 |
| 9/6/2021 | 1 | 1 |
| 9/6/2021 | 2 | 1 |
| 9/6/2021 | 3 | 0 |
| 9/7/2021 | 1 | 1 |
| 9/7/2021 | 2 | 1 |
| 9/7/2021 | 3 | 0 |
| 9/8/2021 | 1 | 0 |
| 9/8/2021 | 2 | 1 |
| 9/8/2021 | 3 | 1 |
| 9/9/2021 | 1 | 0 |
| 9/9/2021 | 2 | 1 |
| 9/9/2021 | 3 | 1 |
| 9/10/2021 | 1 | 1 |
| 9/10/2021 | 2 | 0 |
| 9/10/2021 | 3 | 1 |

I want to get the start and end date for each user's active and canceled periods during this time. I know this involves a window function, but I can't quite figure out how to do it. This is my desired output:

| user | status | start date | end date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 9/1/2021 | 9/2/2021 |
| 1 | 0 | 9/3/2021 | 9/5/2021 |
| 1 | 1 | 9/6/2021 | 9/7/2021 |
| 1 | 0 | 9/8/2021 | 9/9/2021 |
| 1 | 1 | 9/10/2021 | 9/10/2021 |
| 2 | 0 | 9/1/2021 | 9/1/2021 |
| 2 | 1 | 9/2/2021 | 9/9/2021 |
| 2 | 0 | 9/10/2021 | 9/10/2021 |
| 3 | 1 | 9/1/2021 | 9/4/2021 |
| 3 | 0 | 9/5/2021 | 9/7/2021 |
| 3 | 1 | 9/8/2021 | 9/10/2021 |

Comment: won't ordering by startdate, status work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure it out.

The key components are filtering for when the current status does not equal the previous status. This indicates a date when the status of the user changes.

When you filter for these rows, you can just use the `LEAD()` window function and subtract 1 day to get the end date for that status.

```
with win as
(
select
  usr
  , dt
  , lag(status) over (partition by usr order by dt) as prev_status
  , status
from subs
)
select
  usr
  , status
  , dt as start_date 
  , coalesce(lead(dt) over (partition by usr order by dt) - interval '1 day', (select max(dt) from win)) as end_date
from win
where
  status <> prev_status
  or prev_status is null
```

Answer (score 0):

**Updated**

Here is an example:[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=18f396f192bf8363a0dcd04ce70cf4b5)

Updated query,

```
;with cte as (
         SELECT *,Rank() OVER ( partition by usr,status order by dt )as rnk
        ,LAG(dt,1) OVER (partition by usr order by dt desc) as LAG
        ,Row_number() over (partition by usr order by dt asc) as rnum
        ,count(*) over (partition by usr,status) as cnt
FROM TABLE1

     )
Select usr,status,dt as start_date,LAG as End_date  from cte
```

Comment: Hmm, this does not seem to capture when a user becomes active again after canceling. It also doesn't return the proper end date if a user was either active or canceled for only one day.

Comment: @bbk611 I updated answer. I think, now run, how you described it.

Comment: That also does not work. In your example table, each user's status, whether it's active or canceled, occupies only one row. In the table I provide, each user is sometimes active or canceled for periods lasting longer than one day. So their statuses sometimes occupy more than one row.